# Unusual output while parsing Date

Tags: java, sql, date, parsing

I'm having some issues, I have the next code

```
String timeOut = "1900-01-01" + " " + cmbHourOut.getSelectedItem() + ":" + cmbMinutesOut.getSelectedItem() + ":00";
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS");
        Date date = formatter.parse(timeOut);
        java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
```

So, i'm expecting "1900-01-01 21:30:00", but I'm only getting "1900-01-01" in the output, any ideas?

I've tried to print **timeOut** and this is what it prints: 1900-01-01 21:30:00, so I'm getting confused. Did I parsed something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `java.sql.Date` time uses `yyyy-mm-dd` format. 
That's the reason of your hours,minutes,seconds disappearing.

You should stick to `java.util.Date` to keep track of your time.

Comment: So what shall I use instead? Keep in mind I need to store this into a DB.

Comment: Are you storing in sqlite or on serverside? Either way, you can store it as a String.

Answer (score 2):

Just substitute your variables back into the date. Also make the *SS* lowercase as uppercase means something different

```
        String timeOut = "1900-01-01 11:32:00";
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = formatter.parse(timeOut);

        System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
```

Output:

```
1900-01-01 11:32:00
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: Getting the same, I think Stefan is right, Date uses yyyy-mm-dd format only, so that's the reason. I tried your code and it prints the same in my computer.

Comment: Yes, java.util.Date was used in this example.